# Can't generate the APK

Tags: debugging, apk

The App works perfectly in debug variant but when I change it to release variant the build fails and it gives me this error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details, and also on my java classes (setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)) the R tells me it can't resolve symbol 'R'.
This only happens when I change the build variant to release to finish the app.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using react native?

Comment: Did you `check logs for details`?

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska no I'm using android studio

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko might be this? org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.